# ng-bootstrap dropdown's method calling from service in angular

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-services, ng-bootstrap

I want to access NgbDropdown methods from service outside of the component.
Here is the template snippet:

```html
<div ngbDropdown #dropDown="ngbDropdown" display="static">
  <a ngbDropdownToggle (click)="$event.preventDefault()" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuButton">
    Actions
  </a>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownManual">
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my Component I can easily access NgbDropdown's method by using template reference.
For example:

```js
@ViewChild('dropDown', {static: true}) dropDown: NgbDropdown;
...
...
someMethod() {
  this.dropDown.toggle(); // toggle method from NgbDropdowm.
}
```

But in my case, I have to use that toggling operation from service (not in component). How can I achieve that?

My service:

```js
export class Service{
        constructor() {}
        // some operation happened after clicking button from dropdown menu
        doStuff() {
           doSomeOtherStuff();
           ...
           // after completing work I want to close/toggle the dropdown. Not before
           // here will be the code of closing dropdown
         }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass the method to the service. But I don't think outsourcing component state-related stuff to service is a good idea.  Providing the code for service will be helpful to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the dropdown to the method of the service

```
this.myService.doStuff(this.dropDown)
```

Or, declare a variable in your service "dropDown", and in AfterViewInit of the component equal the variable of the service

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.myService.dropDown=this.dropDown
}
```